# Is possible include a trace Id when I'm using SFTP adapters with Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring-integration-sftp

Well I need to include a trace Id in the log for each file downloaded and processed from  the SFTP server. I was investigating and reading about it, especially for AWS but nothing, please let me know if this is possible and please give me some link or documentation for read it. Thankyou!!